# Ajax pagination doesn't work properly in Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have app with several pages and want to do following:
when user clicks on "next_page" button I need to load next page with Ajax.
To do this I try to check if `request.is_ajax()`

Code in my views.py

```
def listing(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    news_list = NewPost.objects.order_by('-pubDate')
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    num_posts = 2
    news = news_list[page:page+num_posts]
    return_str = render_block_to_string('subpage.html', 'results')
    return HttpResponse(return_str)
else:
    news_list = NewPost.objects.order_by('-pubDate')
    paginator = Paginator(news_list, 2)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        news = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        news = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        news = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('list.html', {"news": news})
```

and in my template I have following:

```
$('#next_page').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("/news/?page={{ news.next_page_number }}", function(data) {
    $( "#cur_page" ).html(data);
    });
});
```

When I click 'next' button nothing happens.

When I try to load something else to page with Ajax - everything works fine.

Comment: Have you verified that the event handler is being run? Is the request hitting the server? Is the server responding with the correct response?  Edit: You may also want to post your template.

Comment: $('#next_page').click(function(){
     $.get("/news/?page={{ news.next_page_number }}", function(data) {
        $( "#cur_page" ).html(data);
     });
    });